# Bootstrap breakpoint estimate stepwise regressionn

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply

I have the following data:

```
'data.frame':   500 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ predictor: num  0.446 0.395 0.484 0.919 0.844 ...
 $ response : num  6.65 6.22 6.54 7.85 7.34 ...
```

I need to bootstrap the breakpoint which visually appears to be between 0.2 and 0.4, but first I have created a function which estimates the breakpoint:

[image: prevsvresp]

I have created the following function to estimate the breakpoint:

```
breakpoint <- function(data, psi,tol=1e-5, maxit=100){
  iterations <- 0
  predictor  <- data[,1]
  
  repeat{
    U <- ifelse(predictor >= psi, predictor - psi, 0)
    V <- ifelse(predictor >= psi,              -1, 0)
    
    design.matrix<-cbind(rep(1,length(predictor)),predictor,U,V)
    model<-.lm.fit(design.matrix,response)
    
    p <- model$coefficients
    psi_new <- (p[4]/p[3]) + psi
    psi <- psi_new
    if ((abs(psi - psi_new) < tol) & (abs(p[4]) < tol)) break
    if (iterations > maxit) {
      warning("too many iterations")
      break
    }
    iterations <- iterations + 1
  }
  result <- c(psi = unname(psi), p[4])
  return(result)
}


breakpoint(data=sample,psi=0.25)
```

I now need to create bootstrap samples from the original dataset, I have tried using lapply as follows:

```
bootstrap_samples<-lapply(1:10000, function(i) sample(sample,replace=T))
```

This does not seem to work correctly, sometimes the samples have switched column values and some samples have column names as predictor and predictor1. I have tried using the boot packages following the example from DataCamp (hence the input of indices)

```
mybt<-boot(sample,breakpoint,R=10000,psi=0.25)
```

This only produces two statistics. I tried using a for loop:

```
breakpoints<-NULL
for (i in 1:10000){
  samp<-bootstrap_samples[,i]
  samp<-data.frame(samp[1],samp[2])
  breakp<-breakpoint(samp,psi=0.25)
  bp<-unname(breakp[1])
  breakpoints<-c(breakpoints,bp)
}
```

But this take far too long! I even tried use parallel computing, but it just produces the same breakpoint estimate for each sample. Any idea how to generate 10 000 samples and estimate the breakpoint using the function?

Here is some simulated data:

```
predictor <- seq(0, 0.999, length.out = 500)
response  <- approx(c(0, 0.27, 1), c(6.5, 6, 8.5), predictor)$y + rnorm(predictor, sd = 0.2)
sample <- data.frame(predictor, response)
```

EDIT:

- Create design matrix and use lm.fit

Comment: It's probably taking a long time because you are using `lm`. While `lm` is super versatile, it does two things that are slow: [1] calls to model.frame / model.matrix (to make the design matrix and some other things), [2] calculation of a lot of things you don't need. If you only need the betas, then you can either manually calculate them, or just switch to `.lm.fit`. This does require you to create the design matrix by hand, but the nice thing about your code is that you probably only need to do that once, and then use lighter operations to paste U and V to it.

Comment: Thanks. Does his look correct to you?

Comment: Now, when I ru the for loop I get the following error: Error in if ((abs(psi - psi_new) < tol) & abs(p[4]) < tol) break : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: Well, three things. First, you have hard-coded the 500 in there now. You'd be better off using `length(predictor)` or something. Second, you are using `lm.fit`, not `.lm.fit`. The latter is faster, and you'll get the coefficients by using `model$coef`. Third, the error arises because `p[4]` cannot exist. However, I'm not sure how you got `p[4]` with the original code. The previous formula was `response ~ predictor + U + V`, right? But both `U` and `V` could be `+0`, which means the model would return only 1 coefficient.

Comment: I'm trying to use the provided code + data, but in the for-loop I get the error: `Error in bootstrap_samples[, i] : incorrect number of dimensions`. Can you recheck that the provided data + code is reproducible? Then I'll have a closer look.

Comment: I have rechecked and removed the indices argument. It is working on my side now, I have added the .lm.fit but I still get the same error.  The model returns four coefficient: intercept, predictor, U and V. I understand what you are saying, but there is no other way to update psi, one has to use the model coefficients.

Comment: In the for-loop, I modified `samp <- bootstrap_samples[,i]` to `samp <- bootstrap_samples[[i]]`, since `bootstrap_samples` is a list. I also switched to your original code with the `lm` call. However, I'm getting the same error as with my code: `Error in if ((abs(psi - psi_new) < tol) & (abs(p[4]) < tol)) break : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`. I'm not sure what to tell you, your original code doesn't work for me either. There is also the problem that `U` is equal to `predictor - psi`, which means `U` and `predictor` perfectly collinear, so `lm` should give `NA` values to begin with.